# Save doctrine record without persisting

Tags: php, doctrine, phpunit

within my Unit-tests i would like to have the following behavior:

```
$myNewDoctrineRecord = new Dto_MyRecord();
$myNewDoctrineRecord->pk = 1; //the primary key
...
$myNewDoctrineRecord->save();
```

Now this record shouldnt really persist to the database. But i would like to do

```
$myFetchedDoctrineRecord = Doctrine::getTable('Dto_MyRecord')->find(1);
//result should be $myFetchedDoctrineRecord === $myNewDoctrineRecord
```

I know this could be achived with a DAO pattern, where i replace the DAO to some mock. But maybe there is some possibility so just say Doctrine not to persist, but only to "remember" the records.

Thank you!
Markus

Answer (score 1):

You could start a transaction, and at the end of the test rollback. That way you can still find() the records created within the transaction, but the rollback will ensure they're not persisted.

Comment: yea, good idea! but my problem is performance. I really would like to not access the database at all.

Comment: Well the only other way is to create a mock object, I don't think Doctrine offers any other way. Another alternative would be to use something like SQLite memory database for the tests, because accessing it is _very_ fast.

Answer (score 0):

If your machine has some space then you could put your objects into the $_SESSION. But beware, Doctrine objects can grow pretty large.